# If angles $a+b+c=\pi$ radians then $\sin (a)\leq \sin (b) + \sin (c)$

Tags: trigonometry

If angles $a+b+c=\pi$ radians then $\sin (a)\leq \sin (b) + \sin (c)$

How can I prove that? I know that angle $b+c=d $ if $d $ is the exterior angle of a and $a<d$

Comment: Maximize $\sin(a)$; where does that occur? Then minimize $\sin(b)+\sin(c)$ subject to that constraint. Shouldn't be so bad.

Answer (score 2):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work and explain why you are stuck.)

**Hint:** $\sin a = \sin (b+c) = \ldots  \leq \sin b + \sin c$.

Use the fact that $ \sin b, \sin c \geq 0$, and $ \cos b, \cos c \leq 1$.